# Start background process with ssh, run experiments script, then stop it

Tags: bash, ssh

I am running client-server performance experiments on several remote machines. I am trying to write a script to automate the experiments. Here is how it looks like (in a simplified way) for the moment.

```
for t in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
    cmd1="ssh user@${client1} runclient --threads=${t}"
    cmd2="ssh user@${client2} runclient --threads=${t}"
    $cmd1 &
    $cmd2 &
    wait
```

`runclient` connects to a server that I have started manually. It works fine, but I would like to automate starting and stopping the server as well. That means

1. Start the server in the background at the beginning of experiments
2. Run all the experiments
3. Stop the server at the end of experiments

I have found several suggestions but I am not sure which one is good for me exactly. Some recommend **nohup**, but I am not sure how to use it, and I don't understand why I should redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr. There is also the maybe the **"-f"** option to ssh to start a background process. In that case, how can I stop it later?

**Edit:** in response to the comments, the server is part of the performance experiments. I start it in a similar way to the client.

```
ssh user@${server} runserver
```

The only difference is that I want to start the server once, run several experiments on the clients with different parameters, and then stop the server. I could try something like that

```
ssh user@${server} runserver &
for t in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
    cmd1="ssh user@${client1} runclient --threads=${t}"
    cmd2="ssh user@${client2} runclient --threads=${t}"
    $cmd1 &
    $cmd2 &
    wait
```

But as the server does not stop, the script would never go past the first `wait`

Comment: You need to know what manages your servers (e.g. a VM hypervisor), that's what you'll have to call to start and stop the servers. Check its doc for an automated way to start and stop servers, then include that in your script.

Comment: It would help if you clarified how you are starting the server. Also what do you mean by "server", do you mean a physical machine, an HTTP Server application, a container, etc.

Comment: I have added some details in the question. Let me know if it still unclear.

Comment: Quite unrelated to the question at hand, the code here runs afoul of the issues described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). `cmd='some command here'; cmd &` is not **remotely** the same thing as `some command here &` -- not even when one changes the `cmd` to `$cmd`.

Comment: To demonstrate, `cmd='echo "hello world"'; $cmd` -- you'll see that its output is `"hello world"` *with the quotes*, whereas the correct output is just `hello world`. And that's one of the simplest / most trivial examples I could come up with.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am new to bash scripting, I will have at look at this FAQ. Thanks for pointing to these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track your PIDs and wait for them individually.

This also lets you track failures, as shown below:

```
ssh "user@${server}" runserver & main_pid=$!
for t in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
    ssh "user@${client1}" "runclient --threads=${t}" & client1_pid=$!
    ssh "user@${client2}" "runclient --threads=${t}" & client2_pid=$!
    wait "$client1_pid" || echo "ERROR: $client1 exit status $? when run with $t threads"
    wait "$client2_pid" || echo "ERROR: $client2 exit status $? when run with $t threads"
done
kill "$main_pid"
```

Comment: It seems very close to what I was looking for. The only thing is that, as I mentioned in one of my edits, the server won't stop by itself. Is there a way I can kill the process instead of waiting for it? I assume something like `pkill "$main_pid"`.

Comment: just `kill "$main_pid"`; no need for `pkill`.

Comment: It might be worth another question, but I have the issue that `kill "$main_pid"` does not close the open sockets of my server, thus triggering an exception when restarting the server, as I reopen a server socket on the same port.

Comment: Depending on how the server manages HUP signals (and whether it's maintaining a connection to its TTY at all), you might want to switch to something like `ssh "user@$server" "fuser -n tcp -k 4321"` (where `4321` is the listening port number) to kill all processes holding a socket on that port; another option is using `flock` to hold a lockfile, and using `fuser` to kill any process with a handle on the file. `fuser` isn't part of bash, though, so an authoritative answer would need to know what OS you're running to suggest usage appropriate to whatever version (if any) is available there.

Comment: Thanks. I have found a few related questions that could help me solve that in the server implementation, but it does not seem like the good place to put it as it is specific to my java implementation. This has the advantage of being totally independent of the server. And `fuser` works fine with bash on my side.